# Django login form: where have I gone wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Really not sure what is wrong with my login form and view...I will display it here in the hope that someone may know roughly where I have gone wrong:

Essentially on "submit" - the control flow doesn't break into the form.is_valid nest...

views.py:

```
def login_view(request):
    title = "login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

    context = { "form": form, "title": title }

    print(request.user.is_authenticated())

    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        login(request, user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())

        if username == "":
            error = "Please enter a username..."
            context = { "form": form, "title": title, 'error': error }

        if password =="":
            error = "Please enter a password..."
            context = { "form": form, "title": title, 'error': error }

        #If a password and username exists lets see if we can authenticate it:
        if username and password:
            if user is not None:
                #Checking if the user exists and the user is not none, if so continue, else raise an active user error:
                if user.is_active:
                    #Check that the password is correct and matches up to the password in the User.user model:
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        if user:
                            #One further check to see if user is true, if so let's login them in:
                            #Let's print server side that True if the the user is autheticated, if not print False:
                            print(request.user.is_authenticated())
                        else:
                            error = "This user does not exist..."
                            context = { "form": form, "title": title, 'error': error }
                    else:
                        error = "Incorrect password..."
                        context = { "form": form, "title": title, 'error': error }
                else:
                    error = "This user does not appear to be active."
                    context = { "form": form, "title": title, 'error': error }

        #Display the redirect if the form was valid and if user authentication was successful:

    return render(request, "blog/user_auth/login_form.html", context)
```

forms.py:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        # Alternative method for validation our authenticated user:
        # user_queryset = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        # if user_queryset() == 1:
        #     user = user_queryset.first()
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist..")

            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password...")

            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not appear to be active.")

        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

login_view.html (relevant section):

```
<form class="contact-form contact-form-two" name="contact-form" method="POST" action='.' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="User ID">
     <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Password">
     {% if error %}
       <div>{{ error }}</div>
     {% endif %}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='{{ title }}'>Sign In</button>
  </div>        
</form><!-- /.contact-form -->
```

I don't get any errors - just that the `print(request.user.is_authenticated())` prints neither true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just using the login view that comes with django. There are function and class based versions of it

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url('login/$', login),
]
```

Or class based

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url('login/$', LoginView.as_view()),
]
```

The default form will take care of all of the validation and authentication for you.

### Edit:

Customization is also still possible if you use the class based view. For example, let's say you want to use a custom template and a different succes url.

```
#urls.py
from my_app.views import MyLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url('login/$', MyLoginView.as_view()),
]


# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'my/custom/template.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('some-landing-page')
```

A custom template would look like this. It will take care of showing errors and rendering the fields.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.username.errors %}{% for error in form.username.errors %}<p class="error">{{ error }}</p>{% endfor %}{% endif %}
    <inpyt type="text" class="form-control" name="{{ form.username.name }}" placeholder="User ID" required {% if form.username.value %}value="{{ form.username.value }}"{% endif %}/>

    {% if form.password.errors %}{% for error in errors %}<p class="error">{{ error }}</p>{% endfor %}{% endif %}
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="{{ form.passwords.name }}" placeholder="Password" required/>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ok. Seems so much easier. But how do I customise this such that it displays my own custom form template...?

Comment: I would recommend using the class based version for that. Post edited to reflect that.

Comment: Ok - this is looking promising. Could you give an example of a template as well...I'm just unsure mainly on how to display the form fields and display form errors within a customised form (see my login_view.html attempt)

Comment: Ahhhhhh no! I get the form.as_p rendering but I need a customised form - with customised css classes etc. This will just render the boring Django looking form :(

Comment: Updated. THat's how I do my custom login forms with bootstrap

Comment: Looks like it could work. So in my views.py file with the MyLoginView class would I import LoginView from django.contrib.auth.views then in my url.py file I use from views import MyLoginView ...?

Comment: And the class itself ... what you've provided is that all I need? Or would I need some amalgamation of the class I have and the class you've provided...?

Comment: Yep, just that. You can proabable get rid of form_valid if you're not doing anything in there. All it really needs is the success url

Comment: So all I would amend to my class view is a definition for the get_sucess_url and the variable template_name? Do I need to use this in the return render() line?

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand this - there's no form.py?? You just have a view?

Comment: The base class has a form, and by extending it, we just use that one https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L42

Comment: And where you have 'some-landing-page' what would be here...a regular expression url or a relative path to a template html? Could you provide an example...

Comment: That's just a url name to redirect to.

Comment: Ok so how would I redirect to this url in my urls file: url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')), doesn't seem to work on using 'blog'...

Comment: Also, regardless - the errors aren't displaying as I entered some junk details and it still tried to redirect to the url I would have if it were successful...just doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146009/discussion-between-michael-roberts-and-brobin).